# How to find all the documents that contains “Amazon” in any field as a value? MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

how can I find all  the documents that contains “Amazon” in any field as a value in MongoDB?.

Also, is it possible to search for the field and not the value? I heard you could do that but I am not sure how.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't think you can do something like this with a single query; you can perform this task writing a JS script which iterates over all fields of all documents... or list the field names you would to support for the match.

Comment: Could you paste your document schema ? Is that a flat structure or you want to search in nested subdocuments as well ?

Comment: No its just a general question, I don't have a schema, Amazon is just an example I used. Basically I want to know how to find all the documents with a word I want to find in any field as a value. I heard there's a way to do that, that's simple, but I don't know how.

Comment: You can try with text indexes as described by sriharip316, other way might be to use  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html syntax

Comment: Thanks, I used the text indexes and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) created on all string fields. You can create such index by using wildcard as below.

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

In order to search the desired string, you can use

```
db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "Amazon" } } )
```

Comment: Can you show how to use the created index in queries?

Comment: Ok i will try this, and this will be able to find all the documents with that selected text, as a value in any field?

Comment: db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "amazon" } } )